# Opening a websocket connection to a local server

Tags: websocket, tdd, elixir

I am using the [elixir-socket](https://github.com/meh/elixir-socket) library. I would like to be able to connect to a test server running within the same erlang/elixir enviroment so I can test the messages sent. when I try to use the elixir socket to connect to localhost I get a  non-existing domain error.

As an example I have a test that just prints messages a webserver receives to illustrate the point.

```
defmodule MyTest do
  use ExUnit.Case

  test "socket" do
    port = 9999
    SingleServer.start_link(port)
    :timer.sleep(2_000)
    socket = Socket.Web.connect! "0.0.0.0:#{port}"
    socket |> Socket.Web.send! { :text, "test" }
    :timer.sleep(2_000)
  end

end


defmodule SingleServer do
  def start_link(port) do
    spawn_link __MODULE__, :init, [port]
  end

  def init(port) do
    server = Socket.Web.listen! port
    client = server |> Socket.Web.accept!
    client = server |> Socket.Web.accept!
    client |> Socket.Web.recv! |> IO.inspect
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the client side to connect to a host/port use either the two-argument `connect!` or `connect!` passing in a pair:

```
Socket.Web.connect!("localhost", port)
|> Socket.Web.send!({ :text, "test" })
```

On the server side somewhat counterintuitively `accept!` seems to be doing something different depending on if you pass it a server or a client socket. If you pass a server it waits for a client to connect and returns the client socket. If you pass the client socket it "accepts" the connection (as opposed to `close!`ing it), so the server side code should be something like:

```
server = Socket.Web.listen!(port)
client = Socket.Web.accept!(server)
Socket.Web.accept!(client)

client |> Socket.Web.recv! |> IO.inspect
```